# How to add and remove an input element with attributes using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have to add and remove an input field in div with id "add", So the following code is not working.

```
<div id="add">
</div>

<button id="add-el">Add</button>
<button id="add-el">Remove</button>

$("#add-el").on("click", funtion () {

   var input = $("<input class=\"some-class\" type=\"email\" name=\"email\" 
    required=\"\" placeholder=\"Enter your address\" autocomplete=\"off\">");
   $("#add").append(input);

});

$("#remove-el").on("click", funtion () {

   $("#add").remove(input);

});
```

Comment: you cannot access the `input` variable inside the `click` function of the `#remove-el`. `input` is a local variable of the `#add-el click` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create element using [jQuery(html, attributes)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) instead of string concatenation.

You can use `.empty()` to clear the `<div>` content. Or, define `input` variable outside event handler and use it to remove the element.

```js
var input;
$("#add-el").on("click", function() {
  input = $('<input />', {
    "class": "some-class",
    "type": "email",
    "placeholder": "Enter your address"
  });

  $("#add").append(input);
});

$("#remove-el").on("click", function() {
  //$("#add").empty();

  if (input && input.length) {
    input.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add">
</div>

<button id="add-el">Add</button>
<button id="remove-el">Remove</button>
```

Comment: He also has other problem (in remove) with the input-variable not being global, maybe add that also here, was about to answer :)

Comment: Satpal - what is OP here?

Comment: @Aditya, You are OP(Original Poster)

Comment: Thank you satpal, will upvote and accept your answer once checked

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code.

You have a SyntaxError because you have a new line before `required=\"\"`  and you write  `funtion`  instead of `function`

```js
var input

$("#add-el").on("click", function() {

  input = $("<input class=\"some-class\" type=\"email\" name=\"email\" required = \"\" placeholder=\"Enter your address\" autocomplete=\"off\">");
  $("#add").append(input);

});

$("#remove-el").on("click", function() {
  input.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="add">
</div>

<button id="add-el">Add</button>
<button id="remove-el">Remove</button>
```

And IDs have to be unique, you must not have to elements with the id `add-el`.

And you cannot access the `input` you defined in the `add-el` callback in the `remove-el` callback.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue in your code: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/pZNOwq

Change **funtion** to **function** and it will work. See demo

```
$("#add-el").on("click", function () {

   var input = $("<input class=\"some-class\" type=\"email\" name=\"email\" required=\"\" placeholder=\"Enter your address\" autocomplete=\"off\">");
   $("#add").append(input);

});
```